# Flutter navigation SDK Access and Key

Tags: here-api

Can someone connect me with anyone from here who can help provide access to the Flutter navigation API as well as access keys?
I tried several routes, it’s been a couple of months and nothing yet.

Last time someone called me, I think from sales, but no follow up (two weeks already)
I’m not sure the person knew the SDK existed...

Comment: This is solved now. Thank you all for the help and especially Lucka(Here) for stepping in.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the connection starts from here: `https://developer.here.com/contact-us`. The HERE team is quite fast and responsive, so you should get a quick reply.